# Is it possible to Pass Component as string prop?(Working with component libraries)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I am using a 'reusable component library' provided by my employer to render a checkbox.  The code for the checkbox component is:

```
const CheckboxInput = (props) => {

 const { classNames, label, ...attrs } = props;
  return (
    <label className="foo">
      <Input
        { ...attrs }
        classNames={classnames(
          classNames,
          'bar')}
        type="checkbox"
      />
      <span className="foo"></span>
      {label &&
      <span className="foo">
        {label}
      </span>
      }
    </label>
  );
};

CheckboxInput.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string,
  classNames: PropTypes.string
};
```

I would like for part of the label to be grey and the rest to have the default styling.  I was able to get this to work with either of the following implementations:

```
<CheckboxInput
  label={<span>My unstyled string <span style={{ color: 'grey' }}>{'My String that I want to be grey'}</span></span>}
  checked={isChecked}
  onChange={ () => handleChange(e.target.value) }
/>
```

or

```
<CheckboxInput
  label={['My unstyled string', <span style={{ color: 'grey' }}>{'My String that I want to be grey'}</span>]}
  checked={isChecked}
  onChange={ () => handleChange(e.target.value) }
/>
```

unfortunately the first implementation raises a console error of: `` Invalid prop `label` of type `object` supplied to `CheckboxInput`, expected `string`. ``

the second implementation gives me a console error of: `` Invalid prop `label` of type `array` supplied to `CheckboxInput`, expected `string`. `` . In addition to this error: `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`

Is there some way to get around this error without destructively editing the CheckboxInput component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work if you could you declare a `node` which is anything that is valid to use [in render](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types):

> // Anything that can be rendered: numbers, strings, elements or an
>   array   // (or fragment) containing these types:
>
> optionalNode: PropTypes.node,

```
CheckboxInput.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.node,
  classNames: PropTypes.string
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response(I upvoted) but the CheckboxInput component comes from an external library.  If at all possible I would like to avoid editing (hence the destructive editing requirement above).

Comment: @ruby_newbie Well then I think you could only delete that prop as a way-around - `delete CheckboxInput.propTypes.label` to skip validation.

Comment: Thank you again for the feedback.  I am going to mark your answer as correct because that is the solution I am going to use.  I convinced them to change it in the component library.  Thanks again!